# How to connect to other camera in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, alliedvision

From the tutorial I am able to access the default camera of my laptop by

```
cv::VideoCapture(0);
```

But I have another camera connected, and it has it's own device category in the device manager so it is not "1".[image]

I read documents, it seams like

`cv::VideoCapture();`

is able to take camera ID, filename, or even url as the camera input, but didn't specify how do you find camera like I posted above...

Thanks so much for answering!

Comment: USB3 Vision isn't like "USB Unified Video Class" (webcams and most usable HDMI capture devices). it's a different "device type". OpenCV may not have a generic driver for that (although it really really should). _maybe_ one of the "vendor-specific" backends is actually USB3 Vision in disguise.

Comment: cv::VideoCapture(-1);